# I am not getting proper response in API Notebook in Anypoint Platform Exchange

Tags: anypoint-platform

I have RAML and published to Exchange. Clicked on API Notebook to create API documentation.
Content-Type is application/json

RAML:

```
/orders:
  displayName: Orders
  post:
    description: Places a new T-Shirt order
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            example: |
              {
                "size": "M",
                "email": "max@mail.com",
                "name": "Max Malone",
                "address1": "77 Geary St.",
                "address2": "Apt 7",
                "city": "San Francisco",
                "stateOrProvince": "CA",
                "country": "US",
                "postalCode": "94131"
              }
      400:
        body:
          application/json:
            example: |
              {
                "errorMessage": "Bad Request"
              }
```

Created in API Notebook:

````
```notebook
API.createClient('Newclient', '1a8f9dfc-4919-4170-8b98-7295f40a3e63', 't-shirt-ordering-service', '1.0.0');
```

Get list of products
````

`notebook:

```
Newclient.orders.post({
                "size": "M",
                "email": "max@mail.com",
                "name": "Max Malone",
                "address1": "77 Geary St.",
                "address2": "Apt 7",
                "city": "San Francisco",
                "stateOrProvince": "CA",
                "country": "US",
                "postalCode": "94131"
              });
```

Response:

```
API.createClient('Newclient', '1a8f9dfc-4919-4170-8b98-7295f40a3e63', 't-shirt-ordering-service', '1.0.0');

$0=Client has been successfully created

Newclient.orders.post({
                "size": "M",
                "email": "max@mail.com",
                "name": "Max Malone",
                "address1": "77 Geary St.",
                "address2": "Apt 7",
                "city": "San Francisco",
                "stateOrProvince": "CA",
                "country": "US",
                "postalCode": "94131"
              });

$1={
  "body": "Could not resolve host",
  "status": 400",
  "headers": {
    "access-control-allow-origin": "https://anypoint.mulesoft.com",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "content-language": "en-gb",
    "content-length": "1876",
    "content-security-policy": "default-src 'none'",
    "content-type": "text/plain",
    "date": "Sun, 19 Sep 2021 13:19:01 GMT",
    "server": "nginx",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
    "vary": "Accept-Language",
    "x-powered-by": "Express",
    "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
  }
}
```

I am expecting proper output from this JavaScript command. Also, tried for GET method. I am getting same output. 'body' in response is seen as bad request and status as "400". I have provided all correct values in post method but getting 400 error. Can someone help me on this???
TIA

Comment: Please update your question to an example of the expected output.

Comment: edited the question - I want body be in json object. Actually, I never worked on notebook. I dont know much about it. so playing with this.  Following this link for API notebook https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/1.x/samples-api-notebook

Comment: Are you using API Manager v1 or Exchange to create the API Notebook?

Comment: Trying on Exchange